# Rails3 Routing error. No route matches {:action=>"destroy"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following the guide at, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Ruby 1.9.2p0
Rails 3.0.0

But I'm locked at 6.2/6.3, when I try to add the;

> 

I get the error (I switched the Post example to Specie);

> ActionController::RoutingError in Home#index 
>   No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"species"}

Terminal history:

> bundle install
>   rake db:create
>   rails generate controller home index
>   rm public/index.html
>   rails generate scaffold Specie name:string latin:string
>   rake db:migrate

The path localhost:3000/species/ works but not localhost:3000/species/new

Rake routes:

> species_index GET    /species(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"species"}
>   species_index POST   /species(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"species"}
>    new_species GET    /species/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"species"}
>   edit_species GET    /species/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"species"}
>        species GET    /species/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"species"}
>        species PUT    /species/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"species"}
>        species DELETE /species/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"species"}
>     home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)       {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
>           root        /(.:format)                 {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}

routes.rb

> resources :species
>   get "home/index"
>   root :to => "home#index"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that the plural of `species` is `species` (they are the same).

The answer is in your `rake routes`. Note you'll want to use:

```
<%= link_to "All Species", species_index_path %>
```

See [Section 4.8 - Overriding The Singular Form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-singular-form) in the Routing guide for more info.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, really appreciated.